# find the point two lines intersect in 3d with a mixture of cartesian and spherical coordinate system knowns

Tags: linear-algebra, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry, intersection-theory

I have line 1:

- originating from origin (0,0,0) and magnitude (length) of 7

I have line 2:

- originating from a shifted position (0, 0, 0.4) and the polar and azimuth are also known (see picture)

I am trying to determine the length of line 2 when it intersects the end of line 1. Do I have enough knowns to do this? See attached where I tried to find a triangle and law of sines but can't seem to find the angle I need in the triangle
[image]

Comment: You can write parameterized equation of line 2 and then choose parameter value such that distance from origin is equal to 7.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu are you able to explain further? The length of line 2 from its point of origin will not be 7. However, the length of line 2 will be 7 if taken from origin. If you could provide the equations that would be great. I need to solve this problem for a large set of different points

Comment: I don't understand angles definition from picture. Let $\theta$ is angle between line 2 and $z$-axis and $\phi$ is angle between projection of line 2 on $xy$-plane and $x$-axis. Then direction of line 2 is $(\sin\theta \cos\phi,\sin\theta \sin\phi, \cos\theta)$. Then parameter equation of line 2 is $(0+t \sin\theta \cos\phi, 0+t\sin\theta \sin\phi, 0.4+t\cos\theta)$. Then square of distance of any point of line 2 from origin is given by $d^2=(0+t \sin\theta \cos\phi)^2+(0+t\sin\theta \sin\phi)^2+(0.4+t\cos\theta)^2$. From problem statement: $d^2=7^2$. Put $d^2$ into and solve for $t$.